# Android application copy-paste does not work only when the location is in Russia

Tags: java, android, copy-paste, vpn

I have an application which is an alphabetical directory with pages that contain text. I live in France and this application works perfectly. However, a Russian user has reported to me that the pop-up menu with Cut, Copy, Share... buttons no longer appears when they select text.

I know that russia sanctions removed advertising in russia (which actually suits russian users and penalizes programmers from other countries) but I don't understand why there is a sanction against Copy-Paste? :-)

I hadn't updated my application for a long time and thought that compliance with target API 33 would solve the problem. I just carried out this update and the problem persists. I checked it myself, when I use a VPN to locate myself in Russia, I no longer have the Copy-Paste functions in my application, but other applications on my phones continue to have this feature. So it's a problem due to localization in Russia AND the code in my app. But I have no idea where this could be coming from.

In the LogCat I have this message when I select the text with a VPN to have a localization in Russia:

initializeHyperClipMenu: 2023-07-03 23:23:10.429 4281-4281 HyperClipMenu com.eboops.wn E HyperClip is not installed. 2023-07-03 23:23:10.288 4281-4500 TextClassifierService com.eboops.wn D No configured system TextClassifierService

and without a VPN: the copy-paste function works again outside of Russia initializeHyperClipMenu: E HyperClip is not installed. createMenuItem: mode=com.android.internal.view.FloatingActionMode@8204808

I searched a lot on the forums, but I couldn't find any solution. Chat GPT-4 eventually came to this conclusion:

"I regret not being able to provide a more precise solution. This is a very unusual problem and it is difficult to provide specific advice without having a detailed understanding of the application code and its behavior. It may be helpful to directly contact Google support or post on developer forums to get additional help."

This is why I am posting this message here.

Thank you, Best Regards, Christian